# Running etherpad as a service on raspberry pi [Fail]

Tags: server, permissions, raspberrypi

I am setting up etherpad-lite on my raspberry pi ubuntu 14.04 server. I got stuck trying to make etherpad-lite run as a service, following [these instructions](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki/How-to-deploy-Etherpad-Lite-as-a-service) (I've also checked several others but that hasn't helped).

After starting the service with

```
service etherpad-lite start
```

i get a discouraging response:

```
start-stop-daemon: unable to open pidfile '/var/run/etherpad-lite.pid' for writing (Permission denied)
```

I tried to change the permissions for the file, give writing privileges to etherpad (the user running etherpad), but that changed nothing.

```
sudo chown etherpad: /var/run/etherpad-lite.pid
sudo chmod 754 /var/run/etherpad-lite.pid
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?